# Getting error unrecognized flag --harmony while running nodejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a project on node which i am working on.

This morning when i tried running one of the node files using below command

```
node --harmony watcher.js
```

i got the following error, i didn't change anything expect install few npm packages like nide

```
   Error: unrecognized flag --harmony
```

Please advice

Comment: Obvious question, what is your node version?

Comment: v0.6.7, how do i check what all versions are there in my system and how to use a particular one?

Comment: thanks i updated my node version to latest abd it's working now. Wondering why it moved back to such an old version?

Comment: You can install multiple Node versions and manage them with [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n) or [nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist).